# Unknown Column in 'field list' php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked everywhere but I cant find an answer for this question. I've seen several solutions that have helped people, but when I try it, I see I'm doing everything right and have nothing to fix. I'm making a forum and i'm trying to insert these into a mysql table but every time I try it says:

> Unknown column '6c09e4fe82d47011bf9b25b05946307f' in 'field list'.

The long code is a user id for one of the users, and Its supposed to get inserted, but for some reason its looking for a column with that name. I've only gotten up to the first query with an error so the second part might be totally fine, I don't know.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    topics(topic_subject,
                           topic_date,
                           topic_cat,
                           topic_by)
               VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                           NOW(),
                           " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                           ". $_SESSION['userid'] ."
                           )";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'You did everything right, yet there is an error. WEIRD RIGHT???<br /><br />' . mysql_error();
            $sql = "ROLLBACK;";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        else
        {
            //the first query worked, now start the second, posts query
            //retrieve the id of the freshly created topic for usage in the posts query
            $topicid = mysql_insert_id();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO
                        posts(post_content,
                              post_date,
                              post_topic,
                              post_by)
                    VALUES
                        ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']) . "',
                              NOW(),
                              " . $topicid . ",
                             ". $_SESSION['userid'] ."
                        )";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: seriously...learn to use MySQLi...you probably would not have this issue

Comment: your error messages are useless. Don't pretend your queries are always correct. Having a cutesy-error message like "you did everything right. there there, let mommy call the bad person for you" isn't helping anyone. If the query fails, then dump out the exact reason why, e.g. `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` will be FAR more useful than pretending you're infallible. Even if the SQL syntax is totally correct, there's far too many OTHER reasons for failure anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You're not quoting the string in the INSERT:

```
 ". $_SESSION['userid'] ."
```

Should be:

```
'". $_SESSION['userid'] ."'
```

Comment: @LoganMurphy he states 'The long code is a user id for one of the users' in the question.

Comment: @sammith: doesn't matter. OP's got `VALUES (..., 6c09e4fe...., )` without quotes around the value. Without the quotes, it'll be seen as a field value. Doesn't make much sense to refer to some other field in a record which is in the middle of being inserted, but it's still valid syntax.

Comment: @MarcB no, he doesn't. >:I

Answer (score 0):

```
" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
```

needs to be enclosed in quotes

```
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",'
```

Just `echo $sql;` and you will see your error.

Also make sure you `session_start();`